# Implementing array element assembly

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I am trying to code this in assembly language x86, but for some reason my program crashes. Here is the assignment.
Write an assembly language function that will receive a list (array) of 10 16-bit values and a
number, N, between 1-10, input by the user. The AL function should move the Nth value to the front of the list in
the following way:
Push all values from element 1 to element N-1 on the stack. Relocate the value at element N to element 1.
Pop the stack and restore its elements into locations N, N-1, … , 2

Here is my code

```
    void __declspec (naked) asmSwitch(short[], int)
    {
        __asm
        {
                    push    ebp
                    push    eax
                    push    ebx
                    push    ecx
                    push    edx
                    push    ebx
                    mov     ebp, esp
                    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]         ; the element
                    dec     ecx                     ; 
                    mov     ebx, [ebp + 8]          ; est ptr to array
            TOP:    push    [ebx]               ;
                    inc     ebx                     ;
                    inc     ebx
                    loop    TOP
                    mov     ax, [ebx]
                    mov     ebx, [ebp + 8]
                    mov     [ebx], ax
                    mov     ecx, [ebp + 12]
                    dec     ecx
                    mov     eax, ecx
                    add     eax, eax
                    add     ebx, eax
            TOP1:   pop     [ebx]
                    dec     ebx
                    dec     ebx
                    loop    TOP1
                    pop     esi
                    pop     edx
                    pop     ecx
                    pop     ebx
                    pop     eax
                    pop     ebp
                    ret

        }
    }
```

And I am getting read violation error on

```
    TOP:    push    [ebx]               ;
```

And my program crashes after compiling.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a proper `EBP` for `[ebp + 12]`and `[ebp + 8]`. So move its initialisation straight behind `push    ebp`:

   ```
   ...
   push    ebp
   mov     ebp, esp
   ...
   ```
2. `push [ebx]` pushes a DWORD (32 bit) because the stack is normally 32-bit-wise organized. `pop [ebx]` pops a WORD (16 bit) because the assembler recognizes the 16-bit array. So, `ret` will get a totally wrong value from the stack. Synchronize the types:

   ```
   ...
   push    WORD PTR [ebx]
   ...
   pop     WORD PTR [ebx]
   ...
   ```